# Image Smoothing Using Median Filter

Tags: python-3.x, image-processing, filter, median

I am working on image smoothing using median filter. For that, I am not using the inbuilt functions within the Python library, rather I am writing my own functions. The following code is for calculating the median.

```
def CalcMedian(Image, x, y, gridSize):    #x and y are nested loops, that run over the entire image.
    medianList = []
    row, col = Image.shape;
    k = int(gridSize/2);
    for i in range(gridSize-1):
        for j in range(gridSize-1):
            if (i+x-k)<0 or (j+y-k)<0 or (i+x-k)>row or (j+y-k)>col:
                break;
            medianList.append(Image[(i+x-k),(j+y-k)]);
    medianList.sort();
    length = len(medianList);
    if length%2 != 0:
        return float(medianList[length/2]);
    return float((medianList[int((length-1)/2)] + medianList[int(length/2)]) / 2.0);
```

I am getting an  error in the last line.

> IndexError: list index out of range

I can't figure out as to what the problem is, as this is a standard code used for finding the median, and I don't understand where exactly the index would be out of range.

Comment: You might want to use integer division: `length//2`. But even correcting to use integer division you can get an out of bounds index if `length==0`.

Answer (score 0):

I used you function and some dummy data to test and it works. I get the index out of bounds error only when the value of x or y is equal to row or col respectively.

check, on what value of x and y you get that error.