# Is there any easy way to count pixels in an image in curved sectors

Tags: python, image, matplotlib, opencv

i am trying to create an encoding for my image data. so i want to count the number of pixels in small small portions of my image.

for now i have counted them in small square shape sections.

But since my images are polar graphs and they tend to have curved feature i think it might be better if i can count them in curved sections.

can some one tell me how i can count the number of non white pixels by dividing my images as shown bellow

[image]

this is one of my images.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 16-ish radial lines and 6-ish rings, so there are around 100-ish enclosed areas. Assign each one a unique number (or label) in a template image that you can resize (using Nearest Neighbour interpolation!) to match any image you want to analyse.

Now you can simply make a mask that is `1` in the area you want to count and `0` elsewhere. Multiply the image by the mask when counting to only count the masked pixels.

---

As an alternative, look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58270444/2836621) and consider doing a polar-to-rectangular warp, then your sectors come out as rectangular areas and you can easily count the means over any given radius and angle - see the *"straightened"* diagram at the end.

Comment: thanks for the answer, so you mean i create an image with the number of sectors i want and for each have a different color right. just wanna make sure if i got ur meaning. all my images are the same size, so i think the resizing part is not necessary

Comment: i am trying to see if i can use this warpPolar function to change a girded template image into what i want.. i can't seem to get that to work properly, any help you can give?

Comment: If you click `edit` under your question, you can add in any code you are having trouble with and I, or someone else, may be able to suggest something.

Comment: thanks.. i managed to implement what u said.. do u have any suggestions for a way to create an encoding for this type of graph to be clustered using kmean or some other clustering algorithm. by encoding i mean i mean create a featureset (ML term)